Why can I not put <T> after the constructor declaration?
If I explicitly specify the template argument <T> after the constructor, it builds fine with C++17 but fails with C++20 (verified with OnlineGDB).
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    Foo<T>() = default;
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    return 0;
}

With C++20, the compiler will throw the error
main.cpp:3:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
    3 |         Foo<T>() = default;
      |                ^

To build with C++20, I must remove <T>, e.g.
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    return 0;
}

Why?

In C++20 it was made consistent with the fact that Foo<T> can't be used anywhere else to refer to a constructor. It never really made sense before.

@user17732522 Can you share a link to where in the specification that is mentioned?

https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17.class#2

I wonder why it compiled prior to C++20. We always try to DRY. what was the point in specifying the parameters?
